# Call to a member function isGlobalScopeEnabled() on null

Tags: module, customer, extensions, login, third-party-module

I have just updated my magento version from 2.4.0 to 2.4.6 and i am getting this error on frontend.Please suggest any solution. Also i have custom theme but i am not getting why this error is occuring. Any leads would be highly appreciated.

```
<div id="authenticationPopup" data-bind="scope:'authenticationPopup', style: {display: 'none'}">
        <script>window.authenticationPopup = {"autocomplete":"off","customerRegisterUrl":"https:\/\/dev\/customer\/account\/create\/","customerForgotPasswordUrl":"https:\/\/dev\/customer\/account\/forgotpassword\/","baseUrl":"https:\/\/dev\/","customerLoginUrl":"https:\/\/dev\/customer\/ajax\/login\/"}</script>    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#authenticationPopup": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {"components":{"authenticationPopup":{"component":"Magento_Customer\/js\/view\/authentication-popup","children":{"messages":{"component":"Magento_Ui\/js\/view\/messages","displayArea":"messages"}}}}}            },
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "https\u003\u002F\u002Fdev\u003A16443\u002Fpub\u002Fstatic\u002Ffrontend\u02\u00\u00S\u00\u0loader\u002D1.gif"
                Error: Call to a member function isGlobalScopeEnabled() on null in /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/authentication-popup.phtml:26
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an issue with your theme level: **app/design/frontend/YourThemeVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml**

Compare this file with **vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

You need to pass **view_model** like:

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup" name="authentication-popup" as="authentication-popup" template="Magento_Customer::account/authentication-popup.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="authenticationPopup" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Customer/js/view/authentication-popup</item>
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="messages" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/view/messages</item>
                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\ViewModel\Customer\StoreConfig</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Comment: Yes. It saved my day!